# Using up arrow to get previous command in netcat

Tags: netcat

I'm working a lot with netcat recently to test a server, and having use of the up arrow to repeat previous commands would be extremely helpful. Right now however, it only enters `^[[A`. Is there any way I can change this behavior?

Answer (score 10):

There are 2 possibilities. The first is to use [rlwrap](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rlwrap) to wrap a *readline* history library around your `netcat` program. Another is to use [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html) which has readline built-in as an option.

For example, if you were doing a telnet with netcat you might just say

```
rlwrap nc -t remotehost 23
```

and then each line you enter is kept in file `~/.nc_history` and can be navigated with the usual readline keys. Rerunning the same command preserves the existing history.

With `socat`, there is no telnet option, but for other sorts of connection you can do for example

```
socat readline,history=$HOME/.socat.hist TCP4:remotehost:port
```

If you do not have `rlwrap` you can use socat to run your netcat:

```
socat readline,history=$HOME/.socat.hist exec:'nc -t remotehost 23'
```

---

A third possibility if you have neither of these programs, but do have a `bash` shell with built-in readline, is to get bash to read the commands from the terminal and send them to the stdin of netcat. The following is a fairly simplistic example of a script to do this, using the same `nc` command, and saving and restoring the history in file `/tmp/myhistory`.

```
#!/bin/bash
# emulate rlwrap nc -t localhost 23
HISTFILE=/tmp/myhistory
history -r              # read old history
while IFS= read -p 'netcat> ' -e    # sets REPLY, -e enables readline
do  history -s "$REPLY" # add to history
    history -w          # save to file
    echo "$REPLY"       # write to netcat
done |
nc -t remotehost 23
```

Comment: I'm coming back late to say that the only reason I'm not accepting this answer is because my company's firewall is blocking me from installing `rlwrap` or `socat` so I'm unable to test

Comment: No worries. I updated my answer with a simple version using `bash` that might work for you.